# Content Rotator to display latest posts only

Tags: web-part, jquery, content-query-web-part

I am looking at [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) and a [custom content slider](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Creating-your-own-Content-Slider-for-SharePoint.aspx) and was wondering if these tools allow me to display most recent content only. For a news rotator I only want to display top five news from a List and keep old news archived. Are there other similar tools that can also do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCLAIMER : Never tried this out, so have to check it out if this succeeds. But these are some ideas that could get you started.

You can probably achieve this, possibly in 2 different ways

1. Since CAML query is internally used for the content slider, you might try out for `<RowLimit>5</RowLimit>` inside the query which should limit the results to 5.
2. OR simply inside the custom content slider, you have referred, Add a `for loop` just after `if(itemCount > 0)`. The for loop should mark the count for just 5 records and then break out, which would just result in 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for linking to  my slider, I'm glad you're considering it.  You can change the CAML to return whatever you need.  I'd suggest utilizing the tools I  mentioned to help you formulate the desired results.  Particularily creating the desired View via the UI, then using the Strammit CAML viewer to look at the outputted CAML.

Comment: Nice article Eric. I implemented similar slider using CQWP and JQuery Cycle plug in. I wish I came across it earlier!

Comment: Thanks, Marc Anderson did something similar with a DVWP and jQuery to achieve the same effect too, so many ways to accomplish the same thing.